# MS Access VBA - Custom Column is ListBox (using a value from another column coming from a table)

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Hello Stackoverflow community!

My question is in reguards to creating a custom column within a list box that is pulling from a table using SQL. Refering to the code and picture of the current list below, I want to create a custom column that is not stored in a table, that will be called "DaysActive" and will take todays date minus the StatusEffect Date for each individual record displayed and give the number of days in its own column, say between StatusEffect and Yr. Is this possible? Thank you in advance for taking the time to read through this.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdWindowHide

Dim rs As Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
Dim lstnum



strSQL = "SELECT LastName, FirstName, Status, StatusEffect, Yr, Make, Model, VIN, Deduction, USLicense, RegistrationState, Dependents,Notes, ID FROM InsuranceTable" & _
"WHERE SentRegistration = False And Status IN ('active','add') Order By StatusEffect Desc "

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
Set Me.lstInfo.Recordset = rs

lstnum = [lstInfo].[ListCount]
Me.lstcount.Value = lstnum - 1
End Sub
```

[Link to picture of my current list since I do not have enough rep points to embed it ;/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyYo1.jpg)

Comment: Why would you want a listbox as DaysActive will be unique per row. Use an unbound form field that calculates the current date - StatusEffect Date.

Comment: I want the "DaysActive" calculation to show on every row as it's own column..within that listbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `DateDiff()` function in your SQL.
`DateDiff('d')` returns the difference in days.

```
SELECT ..., StatusEffect, DateDiff('d',[StatusEffect],Date()) AS DaysActive, Yr, ...
```